# Помогите исправить ошибку (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, tkinter, сокет

Написал код, который должен будет создавать окно `Tkinter` с полями `entry` для ввода `ip` и `port`, чтоб в дальнейшем открывался сервер, но вылетает ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\epicb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\test.py", line 381, in <lambda>
    b = tk.Button(se, text='save', command= lambda: save())
  File "C:\Python\test.py", line 361, in save
    server.bind (
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Вот часть кода:

```
def sett():
        se = tk.Tk()
        se.geometry("300x300")
        se.title("settings")
        
        se.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        se.iconbitmap('icons/icon.ico')
        l1 = Label(se, text="plese input ip",
           font="Arial 8")
        l1.config(bd=20, bg='#ffaaaa')
        l1.pack()
        entry5 = EntryWithPlaceholder(se)
        l2 = Label(se, text="plese input port",
           font="Arial 8")
        l2.config(bd=20, bg='#ffaaaa')
        l2.pack()
        entry6 = EntryWithPlaceholder(se)
        entry5.pack()
        entry6.pack()
        def save():
            sip =  entry5.get()
            sport = entry6.get()
            server.bind (


            (sip, sport)

            )

            server.listen()

            while True:
                user_socket, address = server.accept()
                massage = input ("::: ")
            
                user_socket.send(massage.encode("utf-8"))
                


                

            
        b = tk.Button(se, text='save', command= lambda: save())
        b.place(x=250, y=250)
```

Пытался разобраться, но так и ничего не понял.

Comment: Видимо, нужно преобразовать `sip` и `sport` в `int`. Например, `server.bind((int(sip), int(sport)))`

Answer (score 0):

sport должен быть типа int. а он str

Comment: извиняюсь, много проверок стараюсь делать и иногда глаза замыливаются) Я недавно один ответ принял за ответ-ссылку, хотя там она и была нужна) Сейчас всё удалю ;)